# jscript+wsh can't launch notepad.exe, vbscript+wsh can. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, wsh, jscript

**Never mind, I solved it.**

It should just be

```
<a href="#" onclick="runnp()">Run notepad.exe</a>
```

**Original question:**

I'm trying to write a webpage that will launch programs on my local computer. How come only the vbscript version works? Nothing happens when I click the jscript link.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub RunProgram 
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "notepad.exe"
    End Sub
</script> 

<script language="jscript">
    function runnp() {
        File="notepad.exe";
        objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        objShell.run(File);
    }
</script> 

</head> 

<body> 
<a href="#" onclick="RunProgram">Run Program</a>
<A href="#" onClick="runnp(); return false;">Run notepad.exe</A>
</body> 
</html>
```

How can I make the jscript version work? (IE8 on XPsp2)

Comment: Don't edit your question to add "never mind, I solved it". Add your solution as an answer (see [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513)), although if someone has already provided that answer it might be more polite to upvote/mark-as-correct the existing one, or be clear about how your solution differs / is better.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that link. I didn't think it was good practice to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
<A href="#" onClick="runnp()">Run notepad.exe</A>
```

I don't know/understand why your sample does not!

Comment: I originally had <A href="#" onClick="runnp(); return false;">Run notepad.exe</A>. That didn't work. <a href="#" onclick="runnp()">Run notepad.exe</a> works.